# Dispatch and redirect after form submission in Redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-form

What would be the recommended way to:

1. dispatch an event with data contained in the `props` of the component
2. redirect to a different page using `react-router`

following a successful async form submission using `redux-form`?

Comment: My existing solutions all seem to hit the following issue: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3108

Answer (score 0):

I set up a callback function that is called when the dispatch has delivered the function:

**component**

```
onSubmit() {
    const { userEmail, userPassword } = this.props;
      this.props.loginUser({ userEmail, userPassword }, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    });
}
```

**action**

```
export const loginUser = ({ userEmail, userPassword }, callback) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
    .then(
      user => { 
        loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user);
      },
      error => {       
        loginUserFail(dispatch, error.message);
      }
    )
      redirectFunction(callback);
  }
}

// Helper functions
const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {  
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user
    });
};

const loginUserFail = (dispatch, error) => {
    dispatch({ 
        type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
        error: error 
    });
};
```

**reducer**

```
 case LOGIN_USER:
        return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action.payload);
        return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, user: action.payload, loggedIn: true };
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
        return { ...state, error: action.error };
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work around it by dispatching and redirecting inside of the `redux-form` callbacks `onSubmitSuccess`/`onSubmitFailure`.